# Why am I getting an 'undefined' when I try to call my function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, undefined

I am trying to loop through an array that contains multiple arrays in it. The array looks like this. `var numsArr = [ [1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11]];`

I already tried doing a basic for loop `(I = 0; I < numsArr.length; I++)`. and when I try to return `numsArr[I]` I get get back all the arrays but I also get an 'undefined' at the end, after all the array get returned.

This is what I have as my code.

`var numsArr = [ [1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11]];`

```
function looper(){
  for(let i = 0; i < numsArr.length; i++){
    console.log(numsArr[i])
  }
}
console.log(looper())
```

I expected the outcome to to be each array in the array numsArr, and it does return each array but with an 'undefined' at the end.

```
[ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
[ 5, 6 ]
[ 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 ]
undefined
```

Comment: Because `looper` doesn't return anything, so `console.log(looper())` logs `undefined`

Comment: `it does return each array` no, it console.log's each array, it returns nothing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var numsArr = [ [1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11]];

function looper(){
  for(let i = 0; i < numsArr.length; i++){
    console.log(numsArr[i])
  }
}

looper()
```

You don't need to `console.log()` `looper()`, since it already logs the results.

Just write `looper()` at the bottom of your JS, and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your function needs to return a value for something other than undefined to show up in console.log

Answer (score 0):

Your function needs to have a return statement. The result of a function is simply what the "return" statement presents. Everything else inside the function is just operations but the function result is what the "return" statement presents.
Simply add it. Something like::

```js
function One (a, b){
    let c = a + b

    //Here is the return statement
    return c
}

console.log(One(2,3))
```

The function result is the value of its return statement. When a function return `undefined` on function call, it simply means it has no return statement